# Flash Programming ActionScript3, double import swf to the main Stage from another class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Let me explain my situation:
We have a file named Main.fla which links to the class MAIN( it's included in the MAIN.as file). I also have a secondary User.as file with a User class.

I managed to import a classic swf button to my stage from the User.as class but i'm finding trouble on adding the pop up window, when the button is clicked. Here are the codes:

MAIN.as

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.events.*;

import User;                          //Importing our User class

public class MAIN extends MovieClip
{


    public function MAIN() 
    {
            var k = new User();   
            k.logocons(this);      //This function is made on User class and 
                                   //it takes a stage:Object as definition
    }
}
```

User.as

```
import flash.display.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.events.*;

public class User extends MovieClip                                             
{

    var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                                         


    public function User()
    {
      var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("C:/Project/Button.swf");
      myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded);
      myLoader.load(url);
    }

    function swfLoaded(event:Event):void 
    {
        myLoader.x = 50;                                       
        myLoader.y = 50;                                        
    }

    public function logocons(stage:Object)                                  
    {                                                                           
        stage.stop();
        stage.addChild(myLoader);
    }
}
```

This works normally so far When i test the file the Button works perfectly

What i want now is when the button is clicked to show at my MAIN.Stage a pop up window which is also in the same folder named PopUp.swf.

I tried really many things but i couldn't find how i can access the MAIN.stage from another class.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder, do you have a defined interface on `MAIN` to send and receive data? You are basically asking about how to make two *separate* Flash apps interact and load a third Flash application. Why don't you put all of these parts into one SWF? If you can't by any reason, send events first form main to child, so that child would know where to send responses, then listen in main for requests from children.

Comment: A combo-Swf file would be perfect but unfortunately i can't do it... Basically i just want a way to access the stage in MAIN.as file from the User.as class. I'm not really familiar with the event request sending - receiveing and i would really appreciate an example. Thanks for your fast answer

Comment: Why can't you put more classes in one SWF? Do you just draw on stage in either of your SWFs?

Comment: My mistake , my general project requires to make a procedure like this because in the pop up window I will have to make things related to the User class so I need interaction between them

Comment: I repeat, why can't you compile all of your classes into a **single** SWF?

Comment: Well, at the really end of the program all the elements will be compiled in one Single swf.

Let me explain better the procedure:
We have a Main Window (imagine a white square),
In that i want to create a **different** Button for every User that i Add to my MAIN class.(for example 5 buttons for 5 Users)
After that i want every button to bring on my stage a pop up window in the center of the Main Window that includes information of the button that was clicked to bring it on. 
That's why i can't connect the button and the popup in one swf and use it simultaniusly

Comment: You can code a dynamic button, you'll then get the user and construct a button for him. And if you'll have many users, just give it an (expandable) data file that your app will parse at startup, create necessary buttons and popups.

Comment: Creating a dynamic button is simple. The hard part that the popup window  has to appear in the center of the MAIN stage.How can I code the popup to bring it self on at a specific location without having access to the Main stage?

Comment: Why do you have a popup outside of the SWF with main?

Comment: I'm already using a swf i created for Dynamic Button, and another swf i created too for the "popup"

Comment: After searching testing and coding, what i need is a way to sent the stage to my User  class, notice the 'k.logocons(this);' at the MAIN class, 'this' is reffered to the stage, how can i use it on the User class?

Comment: What does this mean? `When i test the file the Button works perfectly` what is it supposed to do? Does **button.swf** have code that you need to access? Also where is this magic "Pop-up Window" coming from? Is that `myLoader` a pop up? Help us to help you

Comment: I created The Main Project (Main.fla here i get the Main.swf), i also created another project Button.fla (of which i got the Button.swf file). I also created another project PopUpWin.fla of which i got the PopUpWin.swf. I only programmed the Button to make visual changes, for example when you get your mouse over it it changes appearance and return to Scene 1 when your mouse is out of its range. At my top code i have not included any of the PopUpWin.swf load.

Comment: I just want a way to do it. What i want to do is to access the .CLICKED event from the User class and when Button is clicked triggers the popup to appear on the center of my main.swf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User.as

```as3
import flash.display.*;
import flash.net.*;
import flash.events.*;
import fl.motion.MotionEvent;

public class User extends MovieClip                                             
{

    var myLoader:Loader = new Loader();                                         
    private var _mainStage:Stage;//MAIN.stage

    public function User()
    {
      var url:URLRequest = new URLRequest("C:/Project/Button.swf");
      myLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, swfLoaded);
      myLoader.load(url);
    }

    function swfLoaded(event:Event):void 
    {
        myLoader.x = 50;                                       
        myLoader.y = 50;                                        
    }

    public function logocons(stage:Object)                                  
    {
        _mainSage = (stage as MovieClip).stage;// now you can use _mainStage  anywhere  on User class.                                                               
        stage.stop();
        stage.addChild(myLoader);
    }

    private function onButtonClick(e:MouseEvent){
         //ex.  _mainSage.addChild(popWindows);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted, Thanks a lot :D